# About install Windows alongside Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, multi-boot, bootloader

My situation is:
I have 1T harddisk.

I used first 300G for Ubuntu. And remain 700 has nothing on it now. 
Right now. I want to install a win8 preview version on spare space.

BUT, I have bad experience that once Windows messed up bootloader with Ubuntu one. Made me very unconvinient.

SO am am I asking. Is there any specific things I need to pay more attention? ANd is there anything I need to avoid to do?

Thanks indeed about any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install Windows after Ubuntu, Windows will overwrite Ubuntu's bootloader.

You will have to re-install the bootloader after you have installed Windows.  This link has a good tutorial on how to do go about that: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: I knew it! :) thanks. I knew I remembered that Win will screw up Ubuntu. damn it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (v8-9) used to come with a rescue option that would reinstall/reconfigure grub for you from the live cd, which just about always worked with linux installs and always with windows for me (even in the developer preview of win7).  haven't tried with win8, but since ubuntu no longer comes with that on the live cd (without installing ubuntu *somewhere* again, i was lost for awhile.  rescatux, however, i found recently, and it does the job nicely.  even the 'unknown linux' entries it adds for what it hasn't seen still boot.  I configured grub manually once.   it took an 8 hour day or two to learn/figure out.  I would recommend: just install windows on the partition you want, then fix grub with rescatux.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/rescatuxdownloads/